# Сайт (PHP) не обрабатывает PHP файл

Tags: php, php7, ispmanager

Имеется проблема с обработкой php файла. Расширение файла php было изменено с index.php на index.cc (CC) в конфиге ISP Menager добавил рядом с .php -> .cc когда домен не приоритетный файл не обрабатывается, вместо результата выводится сам код. Когда домен приоритетный появляется новый переключатель "Разрешить обработку PHP"
Версия php: 7.2.5

Comment: Смысл был в таком костыле вида расширения `.cc`? Первый раз такое вижу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Эт для безопасности) ты не шаришь))

Comment: Кстати, на сколько мне известно `PHP 7.2.5` не является **стабильной**, исходя из этого не советую ее использовать на продакшене и обойтись пока `7.2.3`

Comment: А зачем подобные костыли? Можно же просто через .[htaccess](https://htmlweb.ru/php/htaccess.php) настроить все как надо?

Comment: @Manitikyl, это бред и костыль, на проде такие методы «безопасности» уже никто давно не использует. И да, вам не верно известено, `7.2.5` является стабильной уже давно это `7.2.7` частично стабильная.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов по поводу php- вы действительно правы, уже и 7.2.7 стабильная :< а по поводу переименовки и костыля - тут я с вами не соглашусь, распространенный довольно таки метод.

Comment: @PerfectoWeb каким образом настроить через .htaccess для php 7.2.5? Прописать AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>